# Use "tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering"

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, tensorflow-estimator

Referring to this Link, [(the Link)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17002)
I try to practice using tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering for clustering. The simple codes as follow works okay:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# ---- Create Data Sample -----
k = 5
n = 100
variables = 5
points = np.random.uniform(0, 1000, [n, variables])

# ---- Clustering -----
input_fn=lambda: tf.train.limit_epochs(tf.convert_to_tensor(points, dtype=tf.float32), num_epochs=1)
kmeans=tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering(num_clusters=6)
kmeans.train(input_fn=input_fn)
centers = kmeans.cluster_centers()

# ---- Print out -----
cluster_indices = list(kmeans.predict_cluster_index(input_fn))
for i, point in enumerate(points):
  cluster_index = cluster_indices[i]
  print ('point:', point, 'is in cluster', cluster_index, 'centered at', centers[cluster_index])
```

My question is why would this "input_fn" code does the trick?
If I change the code to this, it will run into an infinite loop. Why??

```
input_fn=lambda:tf.convert_to_tensor(points, dtype=tf.float32)
```

From the document [(here)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/factorization/KMeansClustering), it seems that train() is expecting argument of input_fn, which is simply a A 'tf.data.Dataset' object , like Tensor(X). So, why do I have to do all these tricky things regarding lambda: tf.train.limit_epochs()?

Can anyone who is familiar with the fundamental of tensorflow estimators help to explain? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is why would this "input_fn" code does the trick? If I change the code to this, it will run into an infinite loop. Why??

The documentation states that `input_fn` is called repeatedly until it returns a `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError`. Adorning your tensor with `tf.train.limit_epochs` ensures that the error is eventually raised, which signals to KMeans that it should stop training.